# aws cloudformation s3 event notification to SQS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have written one cloudformation template in which I am trying to create S3 and SQS queue.

I am trying to achieve following functionality:

1.create SQS queue

2.create SQs queue policy to allow S3 event

3.create S3 and notification QueueConfigurations to trigger SQS

Following is my AWS cloudformation template link in which 1st and 2nd step gets execute properly but I am facing issue at step no. 3

https://github.com/maheshvarak89/aws-cfn-templates/blob/master/s3_event_sqs

I am facing following error:

> The ARN is not well formed (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: XXX03XXXXBC36E49; S3 Extended Request ID: bYBRrz0ybftGFwHxFCBXWBI5nRF15COGCL6Q8tm3bNs/e+aWafy+pAIIeUNy82DmOKJcVq1MthE=

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 4):

An ARN for SQS is in the form

```
arn:aws:sqs:${Region}:${Account}:${QueueName}
```

You current ARN is of the form

```
arn:aws:sqs:::${QueueName}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building the ARN, you can simply reference it using GetAtt:

```
Queue: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
```